# How to send files (video, images and audio) from Android to ASP.NET?

Tags: android, asp.net, file-upload

I've been trying to send files (specifically pictures, videos and audio) from my Android app to an ASP.NET server (it HAS to be an ASP.NET server, I've seen many php implementations but none ASP.NET)

I've tried to send them using FileInputStream, Multipart, etc
The main problem is that I just can't figure out how to receive (and maybe also the send part have not been correctly implemented :S )  files on the server side :(
Can you please show me how this is done?

And also, could you tell me what's the difference between using Miltipart or FileInputStream

Finally, as a plus :) , how can I resume an upload after a connection loss?

thank you very much in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For upload file you can create one thread/async like:
public class HttpFileUploader {

```
private static final String TAG = "HttpFileUploader";

private URL connectURL;
private Map<String, String> params;
// private String responseString;
private String fileName, photoParamName;
// private byte[] dataToServer;
private FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
String responce = "";

public HttpFileUploader(Map<String, String> params, String photoParamName,
        String fileName, String urlString) {
    try {
        System.out.println(urlString);
        connectURL = new URL(urlString);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MALFORMATED URL");
    }
    this.params = params;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.photoParamName = photoParamName;
}

/**
 * Starts uploading.
 * 
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
public String doStart() throws FileNotFoundException {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    thirdTry();

    return responce;
}

private void thirdTry() {
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "**lx90l39slks02klsdfaksd2***";
    try {
        // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL
                .openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        // add the params to the form data
        if (params != null) {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "submitting param "
                // + entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                        + entry.getKey() + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(entry.getValue());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }
        }

        // Log.d(TAG, "submitting image " + photoParamName
        // + " : " + fileName);
        // add image to the form data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        if (photoParamName == null)
            photoParamName = "photo";
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\""
                + photoParamName + "\";filename=\"" + photoParamName + "\""
                + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        // upload image

        // create a buffer of maximum size

        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // close streams
        Log.d(TAG, "File (" + fileName + ") is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        // retrieve the response from server
        int ch;

        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            b.append((char) ch);
        }
        String s = b.toString();
        responce = s;
        Log.i(TAG, "Response =" + s);
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error URL: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error IO: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }
}
```

}

After upload success your web api must return response of success if its not done/exception while upload after few  time retry by checking network connectivity. You can also start timer for that to redo task.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the answer, but I`m a little lost... is this all the code for the upload from Android or am I really not understanding your code? Could you give me a walkthrough please?
I am very interested in the ASP.NET part in particular...

Comment: Any luck in the ASP.NET part? I really need that part :/